# Ruby: dynamically fill associative array

Tags: ruby

Something like that:

```
arr=[]
arr[some variable] << string
```

How to accomplish that on Ruby?

Thanks ;)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, i.e., what should arr be after this? I can't tell if you're just trying to set a hash value (e.g., h={}; h[key]=value) or do something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby a `Hash` can be treated as an associative array.

```
# Initialize the hash.
noises = {}
# => {}

# Add items to the hash.
noises[:cow] = 'moo'
# => { :cow => 'moo' }

# Dynamically add items.
animal = 'duck'
noise  = 'quack'
noises[animal] = noise
# => { :cow => 'moo', 'duck' => 'quack' }
```

As you can see anything can be a key, in this example I have used both a symbol, `:cow` and a String, `'duck'`.

The Ruby [Hash documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html) contains all the examples you could ever need.

Comment: Thanks mate i have already found that out :D. Btw what differens in [:cow] and ['cow'] ?

Comment: They're just different classes used as keys. You can have both in the same hash `{ :cow => 'moo', 'cow' => 'moo' }`

Answer (score 4):

Hash is what you need. And you can take advantage of the default value creation when the key does not exist. That's in your case an empty array. Here is the snippet:

```
# this creates you a hash with a default value of an empty array
your_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Array.new }

your_hash["x"] << "foo"
your_hash["x"] << "za"
your_hash["y"] << "bar"

your_hash["x"]  # ==> ["foo", "za"]
your_hash["y"]  # ==> ["bar"]
your_hash["z"]  # ==> []
```

Check out the ruby documentation of the Hash class: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Hash instead of Array in Ruby. Arrays in Ruby are not associative.

```
>> h = {'a' => [1, 2]}
>> key = 'a'
>> value = 3
>> h[key] << value
>> puts h
=> {"a"=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: what happened to the old h[key] = value?

Comment: More elegant solution? Doesn't Ruby have the most beautiful and elegant syntax? :D

Comment: Why do the examples call `send`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
arr={}
arr["key"] = "string"
```

or

```
arr[:key] = "string"
```

and access it like

```
arr["key"] 
arr[:key]
```